# How to use __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros

I am using the VC 2019 compiler to write C code

When writing a macro, it seems that the `__VA_ARGS__` is not defined anywhere

Is there some header where this resides that I need to include or some setting to tweak?

Thanks

Comment: C or C++?  They are different languages.  They both support this feature, but the method for making sure it is enabled may depend on which one you are using.

Comment: I am using C, I tagged C++ to garner more attention

Comment: I think people would prefer if you didn't do that.  It can backfire in leading people to give C++-specific answers that don't help you and waste everyone's time.

Comment: Well this was more of a visual-studio related question than a language-specific one.

Comment: @NiInThTrCo How do you use `__VA_ARGS__`? Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some header where this resides that I need to include

No. Not according to the C++ standard.

> or some setting to tweak?

You must compile with at least C++11 standard conformance or later. `__VA_ARGS__` did not exist in C++03 nor older.

Comment: I am definitely not using an old version as my VS is up to date